# Why create a link like this: ln -nsf?

Tags: linux, command-line

What does this do?

```
ln -nsf
```

I know `ln -s` creates a symbolic link, not a hard link which means you can delete it and it won't delete the thing that it's linking to. But what do the other command arguments mean? (-nf)

**Update:** okay...so I remembered you can find this stuff out from the command line. Here's what I found out from typing `ln --help`:

```
-f, --force                 remove existing destination files
-n, --no-dereference        treat destination that is a symlink to a
                            directory as if it were a normal file
```

But this still isn't very clear to me what the implications of this are. Why would I want to create a soft/sym link like this?

Comment: Even if you don't use `-s` you can delete the link without deleting the original file.  Hard links increase the link count of the file so it won't be deleted when you delete only one of the links to it.

Comment: That's not quite the difference between a hard link and a symbolic link. A hard link points to the same bytes (inode) on disk. A soft link points to another file *by filename*.

Comment: There are also man pages.  i.e. run  man ln.  Or man man, to learn about that help system.  You can get man pages online, too...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the BSD man page:

```
 -f    If the target file already exists, then unlink it so that the link
           may occur.  (The -f option overrides any previous -i options.)

 -n    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow
           it.  This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink
           which may point to a directory.
```

Answer (score 46):

the `-n` option (together with `-f`) forces `ln` to  update a symbolic link to a directory. what does that mean?

suppose you have 2 directories

- foo
- bar

and an existing symbolic link

- baz -> bar

now you want to update *baz* to point to *foo* instead. if you just do

```
ln -sf foo baz
```

you would get

- baz/foo -> foo
- baz -> bar (unchanged), and thus
- bar/foo -> foo

if you add `-n`

```
ln -sfn foo baz
```

you get what you want.

- baz -> foo

that is what 'no-dereference' means: do not resolve an existing link and place the new link inside that directory, but rather just update it.

Comment: thanks for this explanation, i tested this for learning purposes and im wondering after ln -sf foo baz, why does it end up naming the link "foo"? that doesn't match with the parameters of the command

Comment: by default, the link gets the same name as the original file. i.e. you can also do sth like `ln -sf /some/absolute/path/to/some-file` (no second argument) and it would create a link in your workind directory named `some-file`. Now if you add a 2nd param, which is an existing directory, it uses this as a target folder (instead of working dir)

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the options to ln. You'll find -n and -f in here.

> ```
>  -F    If the target file already exists and is a directory, then remove
>        it so that the link may occur.
>        The -F option should be used with either -f or -i options.  If
>        none is specified, -f is implied.
>        The -F option is a no-op unless -s option is specified.
>
>  -h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not
>        follow it.  This is most useful with the -f option, to replace 
>        a symlink which may point to a directory.
>
>  -f    If the target file already exists, then unlink it so that the
>        link may occur.  (The -f option overrides any previous -i options.)
>
>  -i    Cause ln to write a prompt to standard error if the target file
>        exists.  If the response from the standard input begins with the
>        character `y' or `Y', then unlink the target file so that the link
>        may occur.  Otherwise, do not attempt the link.  (The -i option
>        overrides any previous -f options.)
>
>  -n    Same as -h, for compatibility with other ln implementations.
>
>  -s    Create a symbolic link.
>
>  -v    Cause ln to be verbose, showing files as they are processed.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can type "man ln" to find such things:

```
   -f, --force
          remove existing destination files

   -n, --no-dereference
          treat destination that is a symlink to a directory as if it were
          a normal file
```

Comment: i still don't exactly understand what that means

Comment: I think it means "just use the `n` option if you want it to behave the way you'd expect it to, instead of arbitrarily creating subdirectories that you never asked it to create".

Answer (score -1):

-f, --force
              remove existing destination files

-n, --no-dereference
              treat destination that is a symlink to a directory as if it were a normal file

Answer (score -5):

*-f* says that if the target of your command is an existing file, it should be removed and replaced by the new link.  (Note that in Unix-influenced systems, "file" can include directories, links, pipes, etc.)

*-n* modifies -f, saying that if the target you specify is an existing symbolic link, it should *not* be removed.

Comment: Your description of `-n` is wrong. `-f` by itself will not replace a symlink to a directory.  When replacing a symlink to a directory, `-n` is needed to treat the existing symlink like a normal file instead of a directory.